# Bootstrap Navbar Collapse is staying horizontal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Having issues with the collapsing menu still. According to the way bootstrap is set up, when it collapses, it should go into a straight vertical nav instead of still stretching horizontal. It only seems to end up vertically correct when at the lowest screen size and even though only displays correctly on one of the menus. Thank you Gary for pointing out and helping fix the first issue with the buttons and ID's

first image is how it's supposed to look
[Correct Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZK50B.jpg)
[My Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPwnH.jpg)

Here's the [Snippet](https://www.codeply.com/go/Lp0Erj6LM7) of code I put up on codely

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl navbar-light bg-dark" id="topbar">
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAlt" aria-controls="navbarNavAlt" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAlt">
<ul class="nav nav-navbar">
    <li class="nav-item nav-link">
        <a href="tel:1-702-555-5555">
            <img src="image/phone.svg" height="15px" alt="Telephone">&nbsp;&nbsp;&#40;702&#41;555&#45;5555
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item nav-link">
        <a href="mailto:mail@mail.com">
            <img src="image/email.svg" height="15px" alt="Email">&nbsp;&nbsp;mail@mail.com
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Premier Face Punching</li>
    <li class="nav-item nav-link">
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/Stuffnthings/">
            <img src="image/linkedin.png" height="15px">
        </a>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/stuffnthings">
            <img src="image/facebook.png" height="15px">
        </a>
        <a href="https://www.twitter.com/stuffnthings">
            <img src="image/twitter.png" height="15px">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input class="form-control border-secondary py-2" type="search" value="search">
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light sticky-top" id="mainnav">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
<img src="image/VC-Logo.png" height="192px" alt="VC Logo">
</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse ml auto" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
<div class="nav nav-pills">
    <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Web Design</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Graphic Design</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">About US</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Contact US</a>
   </div>
 </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your target attribute for both the navbar is same. Just replace the target attribute and the button works for different nav bar. And the navbar seems to become vertical when the width of the browser is less.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>


<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl navbar-light bg-dark" id="topbar">
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAlt" aria-controls="navbarNavAlt" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAlt">
<ul class="nav-navbar">
    <li class="nav-item nav-link">
        <a href="tel:1-702-555-5555">
            <img src="image/phone.svg" height="15px" alt="Telephone">&nbsp;&nbsp;&#40;702&#41;555&#45;5555
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item nav-link">
        <a href="mailto:mail@mail.com">
            <img src="image/email.svg" height="15px" alt="Email">&nbsp;&nbsp;mail@mail.com
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Premier Face Punching</li>
    <li class="nav-item nav-link">
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/Stuffnthings/">
            <img src="image/linkedin.png" height="15px">
        </a>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/stuffnthings">
            <img src="image/facebook.png" height="15px">
        </a>
        <a href="https://www.twitter.com/stuffnthings">
            <img src="image/twitter.png" height="15px">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input class="form-control border-secondary py-2" type="search" value="search">
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light sticky-top" id="mainnav">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
<img src="image/VC-Logo.png" height="192px" alt="VC Logo">
</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse ml auto" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
<div class="nav-pills">
    <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Web Design</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Graphic Design</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">About US</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Contact US</a>
   </div>
 </div>
</nav>


</body>


</html>
```

Comment: I updated my HTML, thank you for the ID fix, that worked. The navbar switching to nav is still not working as it's intended. I added a couple pictures that show that.

Comment: I edited the above code and now it seems to work. What I did was remove the nav attribute in the <ul class="nav nav-bar" >  and in the second navbars <div class="nav nav-pills">

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, I missed that in the initial code. Does exactly what you said and the fixed exactly what I was having issues with. Thank you so much!